# ¿Puede (a == 1 && a == 2 && a == 3) evaluarse como verdadero?

Tags: javascript

Esta es una pregunta de entrevista:

¿Es posible en `Javascript` que `(a == 1 && a == 2 && a == 3)` pueda evaluar a `true`?

---

Referencia: [Pregunta relacionada en SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48270127/3791844)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Si analizamos [como funciona el operador `==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Igualdad_d%C3%A9bil_usando) vemos que, por ejemplo, si la variable `A` es un `Object` y se compara contra la variable `B` del tipo `Number`, es decir:

```
A (Object) == B (Number)
```

> Antes de realizar la comparación `ToPrimitive(A)` intenta convertir el objeto a un valor de tipo primitivo realizando varias secuencias de invocaciones a `A.toString` y `A.valueOf` en `A`.

### Solución:

Podemos definir a `a` como un objeto con un método `toString` (o `valueOf`) el cual cambie su resultado cada vez que se lo invoque.

#### Ejemplo

```js
let a = {
  i: 1, // Contador interno
  toString: () => {
    return a.i++;
  }
}

if (a == 1 && a == 2 && a == 3) {
  console.log('a == 1 && a == 2 && a == 3 es igual a true');
}
```

---

Referencia: [Respuesta original en SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48270314/3791844)

Answer (score 8):

Podrías usar [`defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/defineProperty) para definir el método `get` del objeto `a`, que lo que hará es definir o aumentar una propiedad interna y devolver su valor:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Window.prototype, 'a', {
  get: () => { 
    this.x = this.x || 1;
    return this.x++; 
  }
});

if (a == 1 && a == 2 && a == 3) {
  console.log("VERDAD")
}
```